# Qual a fase em que se devem editar os dados?

Tags: web-scraping, análise-de-dados

Estou neste momento a retirar dados de um site, com os dados em inglês, através de web scraping.

Se pretendemos, por exemplo, traduzir para português os nomes ou valores dos campos, ou completar abreviações, qual a abordagem mais apropriada:

- Fazer a alteração durante a fase de web scraping?
- Ou apenas fazer a alteração depois de ter os dados brutos num ficheiro ou base de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após uma pesquisa mais exaustiva descobri que o processo a que me referi é chamado de [munging de dados](https://www.edq.com/uk/glossary/data-munging/) (também conhecido como [wrangling de dados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling)), que envolve a limpeza de dados extraídos para um formato de utilização mais conveniente (assim como trata da sua agregação, visualização e treino de modelos estatísticos, de entre outros).

A abordagem mais clara e acessível deverá passar por uma separação entre a aquisição dos dados e o munging de dados.